# Normalizaciòn de base de datos, de tabla impuesto y tabla producto en sistema de ventas

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

por favor ayuda, la pregunta es la siguiente:
En una base de datos de un sistema de facturacion tengo las siguientes tablas:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como relaciono la tabla producto con la tabla impuesto si el producto puede tener varios impuestos o ninguno, por favor corregirme si mi normalización está incorrecta en cualquiera de las tablas.

Comment: Productos_x_impuestos, tabla muchos a muchos de productos a impuesto, si no tiene no cargas nada si tiene cargas 1, 2, 3 etc impuestos que tenga, ej: producto 1, impuesto 1, producto 1, impuesto 2, producto 1, impuesto 3, el producto 1 tiene 3 impuestos.

Comment: primero impuesto e impuesto detalle en mi concepto no deberian de ir a ese nivel de detalle solo tendria una table impuesto con el nombre o descripción como ejemplo iva, ipoconsumo, etc con su respectivo porcentaje, y como dice @Juan es tener muchos a muchos osea colocar una tabla intermedia.

Comment: gracias Juan - @ger, me llamó la atencion tu comentario, me podrias profundizar un poco mas. Te digo lo que yo pienso y porque lo hice asi , la tabla impuesto puede contener impuestos como el IVA u otro impuesto que es el ICE, el impuesto IVA puede tener varios porcentajes 0%, 12%, 14%, etc lo mismo sucede con el ICE

Comment: @Felix el iva recuerda que el porcentaje se debe asignar es dependiendo al producto, no al impuesto en si, digamos en mi país el iva para productos de alimentos de canasta familiar como la leche, huevos se factura con iva del 8% y productos como tv, o celulares con el 18% lo tomo como ejemplo, entonces allí es donde Juan tiene razón en una tabla intermedio de muchos a muchos.

Comment: Gracias @ger entonces me recomiendas hacer una tabla para cada impuesto. una para IVA(impuesto al valor agragado), otra para ICE(impuesto a los consumos especiales), por ponerte solo 2 ejemplos.

Comment: @Felix no!!! vas a llenar tu motor de bd con varios impuestos?? lo que me refiero es hacer algo a esta respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463760/how-to-store-taxes-in-database en la imagen colocan una tabla intermedia impuestos y productos, así como una intermedia tasa de impuestos - juridiscion, que vendria a ser como localidad donde se cobre impuestos diferentes por provincia o departamento.

Comment: En las relaciones de las tablas producto - impuesto tengo claro que debo hacer una tabla intermedia que rompe la relacion muchos a muchos. serias tan amable de indicarme como queda la impuesto normalizada en todas sus formas? porque me confundí. gracias